# Can't type a tilde from Mac running Ubuntu 16.04.1 destop

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, live-usb, keyboard-layout, mac

I haven't had a problem with keyboard mapping running Ubuntu from VirtualBox. However, I just booted my mac from an sd card (live USB) and I can't type a tilde. Changing the keyboard input creates a mess of typing typos. Fun fact: I plugged in another mac keyboard via USB and the tilde types just fine!
I am confused. Rank n00b - so please forgive my ignorance.
Thanks in advance for any advice you might offer.

Comment: Could the tilde key on your original keyboard be broken? Have you tried it with another OS?